# SQL Server : can't Create Table After Deletion

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

After searching around for answers and not finding any, I'm starting a new question here.

I have a table I wanted to recreate. I used the "Script table as -> Create to" option, manually edited the columns I wanted to my satisfaction, and then manually deleted the table (right click -> delete).

On a side note - Any difference between manual delete and drop table ?

The script had a squiggly red error line underneath

```
[dbo].[Agent]
```

in

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Agent] (...)
```

and it says

> There is already an object named 'Agent' in the database'

I tried to run the script I had and got the following errors:

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 7, Line 2
>   Column, parameter, or variable #2: Cannot find data type nvarchar(100).
>   Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot find the object "dbo.Agent" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
>   Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot find the object "dbo.Agent" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

The first error refers to

```
[ActiveDirectoryUser] [nvarchar(100)] NOT NULL,
```

which I'm not sure is the real issue.

I also suspected the constraints persisted after the deletion so I tried to drop them but it couldn't find them as well.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post a full `CREATE` script you're trying to run?

Comment: Who put the square brackets around *everything* for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `[nvarchar(100)]` datatype. Perhaps you meant `[nvarchar](100)` (or just `nvarchar(100)`)

The remaining errors seem to be because it couldn't create this table because of the incorrect datatype.

Comment: You sir, are correct! Thanks (will accept when it's possible)